# Inserting values in a typed map

Tags: java, generics

Why would the code below result in the following error when trying to add to the Map?

`Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'com.test.Test.SomeEnums', required 'T'`

---

```
public class Test {
   public enum SomeEnums implements SomeType {
       A;

       public <T extends Enum<T> & SomeType> Map<T, Object> buildMap() {
            Map<T, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(SomeEnums.A, new Object());
            return map;
       }
   }
}
```

---

```
public interface SomeType {
}
```

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `map.put(SomeEnums.A, new Object())` is not always safe for `Map<T, Object>`. Although `SomeEnums` is a valid substitute for `extends Enum<T> & SomeType`, it is not always the concrete type parameter.

For example, consider this second enum:

```
enum OtherEnum implements SomeType {
    B;
}
```

If the same method is to be called:

```
Map<OtherEnum, Object> otherMap = Test.SomeEnums.A.buildMap();
```

This is a valid call given the signature of `buildMap()`. However, the problem is that the method is adding an incorrect map key:

```
map.put(SomeEnums.A, new Object()); 
//SomeEnums.A is not always of type <T>, so this is not allowed.
```

The code will compile with a type cast (`map.put((T) SomeEnums.A, new Object())`) - with a warning, but that's unsafe and likely not the point of the generic method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just had a follow up question. If I change the Map type from <T, Object> to <Test.SomeEnums, Object>, I get an error in the return statement that tells me the following: "Required: Map <T, Object>. Found: Map<SomeEnums, Object". Casting the return value to (Map<T, Object>) works, but why is this necessary?

Comment: It's because `T` will not always be of `SomeEnums` type in each call. Look at the second enum example. The problem is that assuming `SomeEnums` breaks type safety. In other words, you should NOT cast. Either find a way to create a map using keys of the concrete type argument, or make the method return `Map<SomeEnums, Object>`, because if you always use this enum for keys, then the point of using generics in return type is lost anyway.